# Virtual machine runs on an ESXi shows "virtual machine cpu usage"

Tags: esxi

I'm pretty much new to ESXi and learning step by step. We have two physical servers where ESXi is installed. Which means together we have two hosts connected with several VM's. All of a sudden on of our VM triggers an alarm saying; "virtual machine cpu usage". Even I don't see the host IP on vSphere client and the VMware tools status says; "Not running (current).

Also I see that the particular host itself shows consumed and active both as the same.

what can I do to overcome the issue, I'm actually afraid to mess things up as I'm newbie to EXSi. Please advise.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The alarm just means that one of the virtual machines is currently using a lot of CPU. If the alarm doesn't persist, it's nothing to worry about as virtualisation is all about over-subscription of the available resources.

It's when you get the alarm coming in constantly that you need to investigate the root cause of the high CPU usage. You may need to add an extra CPU to the virtual machine so that it can perform acceptably, or there may be some runaway process or script on the virtual machine hogging all the CPU.